Symfony Translation Command Error: Call to Undefined Method PhpParser\Node\Expr\Variable::toString()
I recently upgraded my Symfony project from 5.4 to 6.4.13. Now, I am encountering an error when running the Symfony translation debug php bin/console debug:translation en command in my project. The error message is as follows:
Attempted to call an undefined method named "toString" of class "PhpParser\Node\Expr\Variable".

Project Details:

Symfony version: 6.4.13
PHP version: 8.1
Composer dependencies include symfony/translation v6.4.13.
Configuration: translation.yaml:

framework:
    default_locale: '%env(APP_LANGUAGE)%'
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks: '%application_locales%'

Question: how to resolve this error?
